# Angular set html lang atttribute in SSR build

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ngx-translate

How do I set `html` lang attribute e.g. `<html lang="en">` in server-side-rendered html?
on client I can subscribe to `onLangChange` and set attribute in the code below, but how do I access html element on server side?

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(document.body.parentNode, "lang", lang.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

as of now I ended up with this solution:

in `main.server.ts` I edited `createServerRenderer()` method to intercept `html` returned as string and just replaced `<html` with `<html lang="xx"`. in my case each lang mapped to separate domain so I determine current language by domain

```
let promise = renderPromise.then(html => {
    return { html: html.replace("<html", `<html lang="${currentLanguage}"`) };
});
```