# Is it possible to intercept static file like .html with Angular interceptor? I wish to change lang attribute

Tags: angular, express, seo, angular-universal, lang

I found this Angular doc about http intercepting.
https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses
I want to intercept html in Angular interceptor so that i can change the html file before it's rendered to the browser. i tried with server but it's very complicated since i will have to change whole project structure.

Basically,

I wish to change `<html lang=" ">` based on language selected by user.
I have already implemented `this.document.documentElement.lang = lang;`, this is changing the lang attribute but when i go to **view-source** the lang attribute does not change.

I tried to follow solution from the below link but i don't understand this solution and couldn't find the method `createServerRenderer()` as mentioned in that solution. [Angular set html lang atttribute in SSR build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759101/angular-set-html-lang-atttribute-in-ssr-build)

Any help or direction will be appreciated greatly, Thanks

Comment: Can you show your server.ts?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `lang` value like this, which will work for both client and server side

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any)
{
}

ngOnInit()
{
  const langValue = "en";//Assign correct value here
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this._document.body.parentNode, 'lang', langValue);
```

Comment: Hi David, I was able to see langValue set to document lang attribute in view source. 
But how to make it work if i wish to assign langValue dynamic value ? suppose i am getting the locale from navigator.language and assign it to langValue.

Comment: You cannot access the navigator's language server side. You need to have separate urls for each language to land directly on the correct one, and/or use cookies to store the preferred language

Answer (score 0):

For using ngrx-translate and doing work before angular bootstraps try using APP_INITIALIZER like this:

```
export function initApp(translate: TranslateService) {
   const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
   translate.use(browserLang);
}

@NgModule({
declarations: [ ],
imports: [ ],
providers: [
{ 
  provide : APP_INITIALIZER, 
  multi : true,  
  deps : [TranslateService],
  useFactory : initApp
 }
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hey @bjlasc01, Thanks for replying,

We are using `@ngx-translate/core` and `@ngx-translate/http-loader` in our project. 
Translation files looks like this.
**src/app/assets/i18n/[locale].json**

I am not sure if it same as using framework internationalization from https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Build process does not produce folders with loacale name, inside dist/browser and dist/server folder like i have seen in some examples.

Any idea if `<html lang=" ">` can be changed in view-source with current setup. Or i have to change my current implementation.

Thank you.